# What kind of simple typo would change the course of the history the most?

Tags: alternate-history

Obviously the cases where the importance of a message or data is acknowledged, the relevant people would probably triple-check it several times, so something like "wrong latitude/longitude coordinate in a nuclear warhead during a training exercise" is not allowed.

I was originally thinking of a case where the person making the typo was one of very few people who know what is supposed to read. Or at some point of history a translator or a copier made a typo. But since I'm struggling to think of an example, I'm not restricting it into such a scenario.

Comment: I wonder how 2020 would be if Stack Exchange had instead been Stack Sex Change.

Comment: Some typo in a sacred text? For example the whole story about the camel going through the eye of a needle arose from the fact that "kamìlos" (a cable used to anchor vessels) got transcripted as "kamêlos" (camel). Or a prophecy (the most famous such being the latin "Ibis redibis, numquam per bella peribis" where the position of the comma turns the prophecy into its opposite).

Comment: Obviously this didn't change the course of history, but there is the amusing "Wicked Bible" from 1631 where one of the commandments read "Thou shalt commit adultery." The typesetter having missed the word 'not'.

Comment: VTC for a lot of reasons. Too story-based. Too opinion-based. There'd be no end of arguing over which typo would be the most detrimental - assuming a typo of any kind would be detrimental at all. Please remember that SE's basic model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. Without providing a very specific historical moment or context, this Q doesn't fit that model.

Comment: This might be an interesting History SE question...but they don't like "what if" questions. We're not overly fond of questions based entirely in this world.

Comment: Maybe try r/HistoryWhatIfs on Reddit?